# What is long polling and how to use it in android For Chat Project

Tags: android, chat, long-polling

i need to know about long polling in android and how to Implementation at Android IDE(Eclipse, IntelliJ Idea, Android Studio) For Chat Project?

Regards

Comment: When you used a search engine to search for `"long polling"`, what did you learn? When you used a search engine to search for `"long polling" android`, what did you learn?

Comment: Long polling means you have to constantly ping the server for new messages or reports in your scenario. so just make a request fire every 900 ms in the background process and update in ui. I can give you an app that does that but depends on your scenario . There is a rcs one api app and a android demo

Comment: @CommonsWare many sites blicked my country ips(Iran), so i can not reach them, and same linkes was not usefull to me.

Comment: @BackStabber Thanks, So I Shuld To Make Class Extends AsyncTask Or Sevice?

Comment: well to backup @CommonsWare i dont think wikipedia will be blocked so you would have researched there before directly posting on SO here's the wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling "the Wikipedis Link")

Comment: Ok, So Server Recieve Many Requnests, What About That?

Comment: @BackStabber hehehe `Long polling means you have to constantly ping the server for new message` you made my day ... long != constantly ... `so just make a request fire every 900 ms` every 900ms **will be not "long polling"** ...

Comment: @Selvin Hehe din recognize that but i think i explained him what was needed for a chat app  :D

Comment: @CommonsWare I did this app using the RCS gsma Api where if the response is recieved then we fire after 900 ms for incoming messages . A seperate thread was there for sending the messages. I think my bad poor choice of words

Comment: @Selvin Sorry for the wrong info i think we both had a laugh  ;) . I added the definition in my answer below. :D

Comment: Have u checked this: https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates Polling usually used lot of resources so instead FCM is suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"LongPolling" is a technique which is often used for instant messaging
type applications. Requests from an application to a server, which does not
immediately have any result data, will 'block' from a return for a period of time.
This mechanism benefits applications as they will consume less bandwidth
and have to do less processing than if they had to repeatedly poll the server.

The design of long polling will depend upon whether you need it to run in  background as well. if yes, a Service will suit you otherwise you can just start a thread like `public void run() { }`. I dont think long polling is really necesarry as it will keep on running and keep using the data think about a socket based chat app. Try to look at `XMPP`. Just a thought ;) .

Comment: Can you please explain. How we do the long polling in Android. The client side implementation. Means we get data continuous.